# How to get endpoint labels in a connection JSPLUMB?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

[image]

In the attached diagram, div 1 and div 3 are connected. There is label on the connection saying 1-3 (meaning div 1 and div 3 are connected). Now when I click a button, I want to display endpoint label name like this "Drag - Drop" connected  instead of div id "1-3".

In nut shell, During getAllConnections(), How to get endpoint label names in connection ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you create overlays like this

```
endpoint.overlays = [["Label", {
            location: [0.5, 2.5],
            label: "1-3",
            id: 'myLabel'
        }]];
```

you just do:

```
endpoint.getOverlay("myLabel").getLabel()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, first get all the connections and for each connection get their endpoints and from it you can get its label:

```
var con=jsPlumb.getAllConnections();
for(var i=0;i<con.length;i++){
    var e=con[i].endpoints; // Array of [source, target] Endpoint objects.
    var label1=e[0].getLabel();
    var label2=e[1].getLabel();
    console.log(label1+"->"+label2); 
}
```

For more refre [API DOC](http://jsplumb.org/apidocs/files/jquery-jsPlumb-1-3-16-all-js.html). Hope this helps!

Comment: This seems to only echo null->null

Comment: @NickMitchell Create a jsFiddle to help you quicker!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created the "Drag", "Drop" labels as overlays as following:

```
overlays: [
   [ "Label", {
        location: [0.5, 1.5],
        label: "Drag",
        visible:true,
        id: "drag"
   } ]
]
```

you can get the source endpoint of a connection using `connection.endpoints[0]`. To get the label value of this endpoint you can simply call `connection.endpoints[0].getOverlay("drag").getLabel();`.

You can get the connection objects by iterating through the jsPlumb.getConnections() like following:

```
$.each(instance.getConnections(), function (index, connection) {
});
```

It works for me. Hope this will help you!